# Recent update for SSH breaks backward compatibility, how do I downgrade to the previous version?

Tags: server, updates, ssh, 22.04

I recently updated a Ubuntu system, and then discovered that the SSH functionality I was employing was no longer supported in the updated version.

How do I revert the sshd.service to the previous release?

(Yes, I do understand that the older sushi needs updated, and that will happen as well)

I tried the work around with the following additions on the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the client:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

But I still see:

```
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/its_demo2/.ssh/id_rsa.pub RSA SHA256:Ml5N2i3iOCN04zqjnpT1y7dQvKOQZT9zsOT5GPE5KFk explicit
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH without password does not work after upgrading from 18.04 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404049/ssh-without-password-does-not-work-after-upgrading-from-18-04-to-22-04)

Comment: Also see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408000/unable-to-locate-package-libssl1-1/) on why it might *not* be a good idea to downgrade system security packages and libraries in general.

Comment: Did you change the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file on the client side?

Comment: Yes I did but I still get debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm

Comment: Ok, I hope someone else can chime in then.

Comment: Thanks fr trying Arthur.

Comment: Oh maybe I misread your question. Could you try [this solution instead](https://askubuntu.com/a/1409528/1066942)? (Generate a new keypair with a more modern cipher, if this is an option?)

Comment: How do I mark this as solved?

Comment: You write up an answer detailing what you did to make it work. 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 SSH the RSA key isn't working since upgrading from 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409105/ubuntu-22-04-ssh-the-rsa-key-isnt-working-since-upgrading-from-20-04)

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem connecting to older devices, and I made it work in Ubuntu 22.04 with OpenSSH 8.9 / OpenSSL 3.0.2 by adding the following lines in the `Host` section of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the client side:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

This will restore functionality of the legacy `RSA SHA-1` hash algorithm for the SSH client.

*Note of caution: Be aware that this will potentially make connections less secure (but still to the level of Ubuntu 20.04).*

Comment: Still learning, thanks.

Comment: Make sure those lines appear within a `Host` stanza in `ssh_config`. I've written a lengthier explanation [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1429684/1077410)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've clarified my answer.

Comment: This is connecting from an old device to Ubuntu 22.04? Client is old device? Does not work for me ...

Comment: If you need to adjust the `sshd` (daemon) setting, you need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` - [read more here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/sshd_config.5.html).