# What happened to libssl1.1 in 22.10?

Tags: ssl, shared-library, openssl, 22.10, lazarus

Lazarus / Free Pascal programs given at https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/fphttpclient that use SSL run OK on my 22.04 system, but they give error messages in the lines `Could not initialize OpenSSL library` while run on my 22.10 system which was upgraded from 22.04.

Looking at the differences between the two systems, I noticed that `libssl1.1/now 1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.2 amd64` package was removed during the upgrade 22.04 → 22.10.

So, running the commands on the system with version 22.10:

```
# wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
# apt install ./libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

fixes the problem. But, obviously, this is not something I would like to do, assuming the software will be distributed to potential end-users running standard Ubuntu 22.10 and above.

What are my options to restore this functionality?

Comment: how did you get libssl1.1 on Ubuntu 22.04? It is not included in 22.04 by default either.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408000/unable-to-locate-package-libssl1-1

Comment: @Esther  I don't remember doing any special about this. However, my system is a very old one (>5 years) and I am doing a "normal" release upgrade every 6 months.