# Problem downloading .deb for libssl.so.1.1

Tags: command-line, dpkg

Running Ubuntu 22.04.1 off a usb. Trying to jailbreak my phone with palera1n. The commands worked before but I had to rejailbreak and now after running these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libimobiledevice-utils libusbmuxd-tools git curl python3-pip -y
```

and then attempting to run these commands to fix libssl.so.1.1 error:

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
```

When running the dpkg command it outputs:

```
Cannot access archive libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb": No such file or directory.
```

Any fixes?

Comment: Please see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408000/unable-to-locate-package-libssl1-1

Comment: Also, the command `wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb` doesn't download anything, as the file doesn't exist. So no wonder you get the error you get.

Comment: That `2.16` needs to be changed to `2.17` in order for everything to work. The library was updated on February 7, 2023 

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb
```

Don't forget using `sudo sh pairingdevice.sh`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me with version 2.19 for Ubuntu 22.04.

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb
```